# regex testing pathname and mobile device

Tags: javascript, regex, user-agent

```
if( /f(?=1-)/.test(window.location.pathname) ) {
 if( !/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/gi.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
     window.location.href=  "/";
    }
 }
```

I am testing if the pathname starts with  `f1-` and if it does and it is NOT a specified userAgent go back to the homepage. Though even on the userAgent it still is redirecting me...is my regex incorrect?

Comment: What is your userAgent?

Comment: I was using the userAgent Switcher on google chrome with the android and iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would the pathname start with `f1-`, wouldn't it normally start with `/` ?

Do you need a regex to see if a string starts with something:

```
var UA = /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/gi.test(navigator.userAgent);

if(!(UA) && window.location.pathname.indexOf('/f1-')===0) {
    window.location.href=  "/";
}
```

Comment: by adding the /f1- to my code and escaping the / it worked for me fine. It doesn't like to work on the chrome userAgent switcher but it does work on my phone

Comment: Okay, the pathname normally always starts with `/`, so you need that indeed. I wouldn't use a regex to check start of string, but that's up to you.

Comment: Well reason i am using regex is I am testing hrefs as well as this is javascript and there are ways around it ;) and there are crumbs to lead back to this specific url so if that href has that specific url it should do the same as well